# How to quickly change user profile in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

Is there any keyboard shortcut for changing it? Google couldn't solve my problem.

I'm using too many different profiles for my blog and their social media profiles etc.
Sometimes it's getting annoying to open it with mouse from top corner. I love shortcuts.

Comment: This isn't a keyboard shortcut, but if you right-click it, you get a quick-access menu.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Windows and Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>▼</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>►</kbd> or <kbd>◄</kbd> until you reach the user you want.

Mac OS:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then <kbd>▼</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>►</kbd> or <kbd>◄</kbd> until you reach the user you want.

**Note**

On Chrome 78 this keyboard shortcut opens the profile menu and focuses your previous used profile, so after you invoked the menu it's enough to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to quickly switch from one profile to the other.

Comment: What an "EASY SHORTCUT" Ctrl+Shift+M then ▼ then Enter then ► or ◄ until you reach the user you want.

Please add few more keypresses Google :)

Comment: Note: For Mac users you'll need to use ⌘ Cmd instead of Ctrl

Comment: as a side note, just pressing `Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + M` is what brings up the menu. You can use the directional arrows and enter key to navigate that menu but you don't need to continuously hold down the hotkey - and pressing esc will close the menu should you need that.

Comment: This solution works for me on `Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)`. **it should be the solution**

Comment: @JacopKane As Daniel has stated, this should still be the answer to the question, as it has both Mac and Windows shortcuts. Whereas Patrick's answer only has a Mac shortcut.

Comment: @imtheman Okay, accepted this one

Comment: Cheers! good time saver!

Comment: This appears to not work any more (on Windows, for me, at least).

Answer (score 39):

Chrome now has a "People" menu. If you have two profiles, say "Work" and "Personal",

1. go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts
2. click the <kbd>+</kbd>
3. choose "Google Chrome.app"
4. add one keyboard shortcut for "Work" and another one for "Personal".

Comment: Can we use a similar shortcut property for switching to an already open incognito window?

Comment: awesome, exactly what i was looking for thank you!

Comment: Perfect solution! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @shivshnkr The menu item names in the Keyboard Shortcut preferences need to be exact, but I don't see a menu item to switch between windows in Chrome, probably because it's an OS-level thing. The default is ⌘-` (backtick) which is under Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Keyboard -> Move focus to next window

Comment: can you share a video of what you suggested I could not understand from your answer how to do it.

Comment: Specifying the OS where this would work would be helpful. Is this for Mac?

Comment: I edited this to clarify it is for Mac.

Comment: Can somone give more explanation? just writing in the keyboard shourtcut "work" or "personal" does not work. not sure if chrome has changed. but it seems that we should specify a bit more than just the name of the profile.

Comment: @EsseTi The name of the menu item in the Keyboard Shortcuts has to be *exactly* the name of the menu item. Chrome now adds your first name in the profile, so the menu item title might be `Personal (Esse)`

Comment: You deserve an award for this answer.

Answer (score 24):

Below are instructions to setup your own quick shortcuts for Mac OS X
in case you consider Chrome's default combination of keys too long for a "shortcut".

Part 1.

1. Launch Chrome
2. Click "Preferences" in "Chrome" menu in the top bar.
   You should see more than one user profile in the section People.
   For example, "Work" and "Personal" or "Work" and your name.
3. Click on "Personal" or your name and click "Edit" below it.
4. Rename it to "Gpersonal" or something else.
   I am not sure why this is needed, but it worked for me only after renaming it.

Part 2.

1. Go to Mac OS X Settings
   You can do it via Apple icon in the top left corner.
2. Go to "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts".
3. Choose "App Shortcuts" in the left pane.
4. Click "+" in the bottom.
5. In "Application" section choose "Google Chrome"
6. In "Menu Title" type first profile name. For example, "Work" without quotes.
7. Choose a keyboard shortcut, for example, "Cmd+Shift+,".
8. Click "Add".
9. Click "+" in the bottom.
10. In "Menu Title" type first profile name. For example, "GPersonal" without quotes.
11. Choose a keyboard shortcut, for example, "Cmd+Shift+.".
12. Click "Add".
13. You can go back to Chrome now and try new shortcuts.

Comment: Can we use a similar shortcut property for switching to an already open incognito window?

Answer (score 15):

For Mac OS X :

Since there is the People menu and in Mac OS X, you can access all items in menus with a search in the Help menu, you can also do :

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> (to access the search in the help menu)

<kbd>[name of the profile]</kbd>

<kbd>▼</kbd>

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

What is nice with this tip is that, it works also to have a "shortcut" to menu item that do not natively have one :-)

Comment: A nice alternative for keyboard people like me, thanks

Comment: This is objectively the best answer.  Nice!

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version of Chrome, there is now a Menu option "People" at the top, with items for each profile you maintain. Since this is now a built-in menu, it is possible (at least on OSX) to bind a custom keyboard shortcut to switch to a specific profile.

For example, I have a shortcut set up for "Personal" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) and "Work" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) - you just have to make sure your profiles aren't named exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

First we need to access Chrome profile switcher options; the default keyboard shortcut for this is “Ctrl + Shift + M.” Just press “Ctrl + Shift + M” on any active window in Chrome, and the profile switcher should drop down from the top-right corner.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. Additionally,,, it works!

Answer (score 2):

I created a small autohotkey script if you want to automate shortcut.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

    ^+k::SendInput ^+m{up}{up}{enter}{right}{right}

    ^+m::
        WinGetPos,,, Width,, A
        ControlClick % "x" width - 175 " y10",,, Right
        SendInput {down}
    Return

#IfWinActive
```

Note: You may need to change the values of `175` and `10` depending upon your system resolution

Comment: Wouldn't be a SuperUser answer without ❤ of Autohotkey

Comment: @Jay! I am a big fan of AHK. My personal AHK file is over 2000 lines of code written by me in just 2-4 years :)

Answer (score 2):

All the answers are not the best if you have created many Chrome profiles, for example you have created more than 1000 profiles, you will find that it is so hard to find the specific profile you want to open. As Chrome has remove the option to create desktop shortcut, so you can not search the specific profile easily with PC file search function.

Here is the solution（for MAC Users）:

1. open a Chrome tab and type the following into address bar。
   `chrome://profile-internals/`
2. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search the profiles name, click it and you see the order number of the profile.
   [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1072.png)
3. open terminal and paste the following code and then enter, you will easily open the profile you want, do not need to search it one by one.

```bash
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --profile-directory="Profile 41"
```

change 41 to the order number you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure about switching between too many profiles but if you have just 2 profiles in google chrome, you can switch between them easily using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> keyboard shortcut. I use this everyday and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

1. install [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/),
2. setup second profile there
3. enjoy having two Chrome apps in the Dock

Method works well both on MAc and Windows.

[image: two Chrome browsers with different profiles]

Answer (score -2):

This is helpful
Ctrl+Shift+M then ▼ then Enter then ► or ◄ until you reach the user you want.

But this is even faster way to switch :
In the upper right corner of the browser window right-click on the current profile name and then select the other profile, this i find much faster

Comment: The first part of your answer is a copy of another answer. The second part doesn't answer the question, which is asking for a keyboard shortcut.