# How to switch Google Chrome user profiles with one keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

#### Question

I have set up a "Work" and a "Home" user profile in Google Chrome.

[image: Google Chrome user profile switching page]

I'd like to switch between them with *one* keyboard shortcut. Is that somehow possible?

#### What I don't want

1. Using a long sequence of keyboard shortcuts

   It is possible to switch the user profile with a whole sequence of keyboard shortcuts as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131745/7137).

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to select the *User* button
   - <kbd>Arrow down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select *Switch person*
   - <kbd>Arrow left</kbd> or <kbd>Arrow right</kbd> to select the user profile
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the profile

   I don't want to hit that many keys because switching profiles is an operation I perform fairly often.
2. Starting Google Chrome with different user profiles

   Another way I don't want to do is to start Google Chrome with different parameters as described here: [How to start different profiles with Google Chrome when startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/201885/how-to-start-different-profiles-with-google-chrome-when-startup)
3. Google Chrome extensions that have their own concept of "profile"

   I'm not looking for extensions that introduce their own concept of "profile", like [Profile Swapper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/profile-swapper-by-qbm5/hfinhgmafkcjmnjffomapijndpeimlif) or [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/nccllfnllopfpcbjdgjdlfmomnfgnnbk?hl=en). I want to keep using the user profiles Google Chrome provides out of the box.

#### Possible ideas

1. A one-mouse-click-solution would be fine, too.
2. Perhaps, there is a Google Chrome extension that does that. I haven't found one yet.
3. Perhaps, there is a Google Chrome extension that enables one to assign keyboard shortcuts to Google Chrome functions. I haven't found one yet.
4. Perhaps, Google Chrome has this feature out of the box and one just needs to enable it in about:flags. I haven't found anything there yet; only *Enable new profile management system*.

#### System

- Windows 7
- Google Chrome 41.0.2272.89

#### Edit 24.03.2015: My current solution using AutoHotkey

This solution using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) was inspired by [Zvi Twersky's answer](https://superuser.com/a/893509/32245).

```
; Switch to user profile "Home" with Ctrl+Shift+1
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^+1::
Send, ^+M
Send, {Down}{Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, {Right}{Enter}
return

; Switch to user profile "Work" with Ctrl+Shift+2
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
^+2::
Send, ^+M
Send, {Down}{Enter}
Sleep, 300
Send, {Left}{Enter}
return
```

Comment: We won't or perhaps I should say shouldn't be providing you possible Chrome extensions that give you this capability since any answer that did given the last most recent changes to Chrome will be extremely time sensitive and short lived.  You might have to accept an answer that simply indicates its not possible given the restrictions you have provided.  I think the simplest solution might actually be to simply *disable* the *new* profile management system.

Comment: You can add the profile to the end of a Chrome shortcut and have a shortcut for each user:

For example in Windows 7:
Windows 7: “C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe” –profile-directory=”Profile 1”

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/21055/chrome-create-shortcut-launch-an-user-profile-directly/

Comment: You can also make an Autohotkey remapping for that.

Comment: For Mac users: https://superuser.com/a/954380/219323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AHK should help. With AutoHotkey you can remap any combination of keystrokes into one keystroke so that should help.

To remap say the <kbd>M</kbd> key to <kbd>Arrow down</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> you would do:

```
M::
Send, {DOWN}{Enter}
return
```

Comment: Holy cow, it's working. Thanks a lot! I've added my working solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check, if it is work for you

```
/**
 * Description : AutoHotKey script bring specific Chrome Profile windows to the front.
 *             : While Chrome is active press Ctrl+1 ... Ctrl+5 to activate another profile.
 * Tested with : Chrome v84
 * Freelancer  : Art G. - https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~017155e179702d4657
 * Version     : 2020-07-17
 */

#Warn
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetBatchLines -1
SetTitleMatchMode 2

GroupAdd ChromeWindow, ahk_exe chrome.exe ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1

#IfWinActive ahk_group ChromeWindow
    ^1:: ActivateProfile("Default")
    ^2:: ActivateProfile("Profile 2")
    ^3:: ActivateProfile("Profile 3")
    ^4:: ActivateProfile("Profile 4")
    ^5:: ActivateProfile("Profile 5")
#IfWinActive

ActivateProfile(profile) {
    static profiles := {}, hwnds := {}

    If (!profiles[profile]) {
        FileRead preferences, % SubStr(A_AppData, 1, -8) "\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\" profile "\Preferences"
        profiles[profile] := {}

        RegExMatch(preferences, "O)""name"":\s*""(.+?)""", match)
        profiles[profile]["name"] := match[1]

        RegExMatch(preferences, "O)""given_name"":\s*""(.+?)""", match)
        profiles[profile]["given_name"] := match[1]
    }

    WinGet hwndList, List, ahk_group ChromeWindow
    Loop % hwndList {
        hwnd := hwndList%A_Index%
        If (!hwnds[hwnd]) {
            title := Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hwnd).accName
            RegExMatch(title, "O)^.+Google Chrome . .*?([^(]+[^)]).?$", match)
            hwnds[hwnd] := match[1]
        }

        If (hwnds[hwnd] == profiles[profile]["name"] || hwnds[hwnd] == profiles[profile]["given_name"]) {
            WinActivate ahk_id %hwnd%

            For hwnd In hwnds {
                If (!WinExist("ahk_id" hwnd))
                    hwnds.Delete(hwnd)
            }

            Return
        }
    }

    Run chrome.exe --profile-directory="%profile%"
}

Acc_Init() {
    static h := DllCall("LoadLibrary", Str,"oleacc", Ptr)
}

Acc_ObjectFromWindow(hwnd, objectId := 0) {
    static OBJID_NATIVEOM := 0xFFFFFFF0

    objectId &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    If (objectId == OBJID_NATIVEOM)
        riid := -VarSetCapacity(IID, 16) + NumPut(0x46000000000000C0, NumPut(0x0000000000020400, IID, "Int64"), "Int64")
    Else
        riid := -VarSetCapacity(IID, 16) + NumPut(0x719B3800AA000C81, NumPut(0x11CF3C3D618736E0, IID, "Int64"), "Int64")

    If (DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", Ptr,hwnd, UInt,objectId, Ptr,riid, PtrP,pacc:=0) == 0)
        Return ComObject(9, pacc, 1), ObjAddRef(pacc)
}
```