# multiple google accounts - how to switch between them quickly?

Tags: gmail, google-accounts

My company uses google calendar, gmail, docs, etc.... and I do too for my personal stuff. how do i quickly go from personal to corporate accounts. I noticed there is an increment number `1` or `0` I can change in the navigation bar, and it's not terribly slow because I'm signed into them already, but is there an even faster way?

Comment: Doesn't [this](http://superuser.com/a/444656/270195) work for you ?

Comment: i am thinking of something like: `cml+l` type `gmail corp` or `gmail me` `enter`. there isn't a chrome plugin/extension for shortcuts like this?

Comment: You can do that. Posting as an answer shortly

Comment: Sweet. yea, don't want to change the chrome account, just want to enter the gmail corp/personal, docs corp/per, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind little redirection then you can use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-alias/nelckmdlallhkgniidbfafekeldjnakb/related?hl=en) to set aliases for links.

[image: Set aliases for URLS]

If you are trying to do this for gmail you must be signed into both the accounts in the same Chrome profile. Copy the URL once you see inbox and use that to set alias.

You can try [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-alias-rewrite/mmapmkalidadbdlciojomkedmgcafgef/related?hl=en) too if you like to have options