# How to restore profile focus in Chrome 79 when switching with ⌘/Ctrl+shift+M?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

As stated in [How to quickly change user profile in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/438039/how-to-quickly-change-user-profile-in-google-chrome/444656#444656):

> "On Chrome 78 this keyboard shortcut opens the profile menu and focuses your previous used profile"

On Chrome 79 that focus disappeared. Until 78 one could just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> (in most cases). Now however, one is forced to <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> navigate to the desired profile to switch to, by definition. 
Is there a way to get 78 behaviour back?

Comment: It's not a solution, but this was also reported on a google thread: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23330948

Comment: Windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: @harrymc All platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed with v.80 (and therefore question is now obsolete). Yay!

Answer (score 1):

The new profile switcher seems to be here to stay.
In the post
[Keyboard shortcut to change user profiles no longer works](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23330948?hl=en)
a Google employee also expressed his hope that this would change in the future.

In the meantime, it is less painful to get to the profiles list using the
<kbd>Up</kbd> key, which needs less key-presses than when using the
<kbd>Down</kbd> key.

A workaround might be to use a macro product, such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
on Windows, to create a keyboard shortcut that will do all this,
including the arrow keys, with one keyboard shortcut.
I can help with creating such a AutoHotkey script if you wish.

The last possibility that I can see is opening a bug report with Google,
although that will not solve the immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting used to 3 x ↑ now. Too bad they changed it. I'm on Mac, so AutoHotkey won't work (and frankly, I'm not willing to go there).

Comment: Just a remark to others that there exist Mac equivalents to AutoHotkey, although that's irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to disable the chrome flag for the new profile menu. Go to chrome://flags and disable the #profile-menu-revamp experiment.

This is from an answer at the support forum in https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23330948